# Using if and stop doesnt work the same as stopifnot

Tags: r, function

I've been working on this school project...
We have a very specific task. If the conditions arent true, I need to stop the code and print a custom message.
First I did this:
This one works, but I can't add a custom warning message I have to include.

```
alpha <- function(pstar, p){
    stopifnot(is.numeric(pstar), length(pstar) == 1, is.numeric(p), is.vector(p), p > 0)
    n <- length(p)
    ((sqrt((sum((pstar - p[1:n])^2)) / n)) / pstar) * 100
}
```

I thought I´d use if and stop instead.

```
alpha <- function(pstar, p){
    if (!(is.numeric(pstar) && length(pstar) == 1 && is.numeric(p) && is.vector(p) && p > 0))
        return(stop("Bad input"))
    n <- length(p)
    ((sqrt((sum((pstar - p[1:n])^2)) / n)) / pstar) * 100
}
```

But I always get this warning message back:

*Warning message:
In is.numeric(pstar) && length(pstar) == 1 && is.numeric(p) && is.vector(p) &&  :
'length(x) = 5 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'*

I can't find where the problem is.
Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

`stopifnot()` allows a message to be attached to each of the tests, for example the first two tests could be messaged like:

```
stopifnot("Pstar must be numerical" = is.numeric(pstar), 
          "pstar must be of length 1" = length(pstar) == 1, 
           is.numeric(p), is.vector(p), p > 0)

 > alpha("a", 20)
 Error in alpha("a", 20) : Pstar must be numerical 
 > alpha(c(2,2), 20)
 Error in alpha(c(2, 2), 20) : pstar must be of length 1 > alpha("a", 20)
```

Does this solve your problem?

Incidentally, your second function appears to work:

```
alpha("a", 20)
 Error in alpha("a", 20) : Bad input
alpha(c(2,2), 20)
  Error in alpha(c(2, 2), 20) : Bad input
alpha(2, 1)
  [1] 50
```

Comment: I didnt know about the stopifnot message, thank you. The version works on your examples, but when I use ones from our task. such us: alpha(47, c(42, 47, 46, 49, 48)), it returns Warning message:
In is.numeric(pstar) && length(pstar) == 1 && is.numeric(p) && is.vector(p) &&  :
  'length(x) = 2 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

Comment: * I need p to be a vector

Comment: I think this is because several tests fail and so 2 is not TRUE (1) or FALSE (0) anymore.  Try `any(is.numeric(pstar) && ...`